# Get count of consecutive dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

For example there is some table with dates:

```
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-01-06
2015-01-07
2015-01-11
```

I have to write SQL query, which will return the count of consecutive dates starting from every date in the table. So the result will be like:

```
2015-01-01   1
2015-01-02   2
2015-01-03   3
2015-01-06   1
2015-01-07   2
2015-01-11   1
```

It seems to me that I should use the `LAG` and `LEAD` functions, but now I can't see how.

Comment: Shouldn't the sequence be `3,2,1,2,1,1` instead of `1,2,3,1,2,1`? You mentioned the start, not the end.

Comment: Sorry, I ment ending with each date.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #T ( MyDate DATE) ;
INSERT #T VALUES ('2015-01-01'),('2015-01-02'),('2015-01-03'),('2015-01-06'),('2015-01-07'),('2015-01-11')

SELECT 
    RW=ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY GRP  ORDER BY MyDate) ,MyDate
FROM
(
SELECT 
    MyDate, DATEDIFF(Day, '1900-01-01' , MyDate)- ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY MyDate ) AS GRP
FROM #T 
) A

DROP TABLE #T;
```

Comment: Well done, that's quite clever, and much faster than the other solutions

Comment: To gain better performance it's better to add an index on MyDate column (because of using WINDOW FUNCTION )

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `CTE`:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT [Date],        
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) AS rn,
          CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, PrevDate, [Date]) IS NULL THEN 0
               WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, PrevDate, [Date]) > 1 THEN 0
               ELSE 1
          END AS flag
   FROM (
      SELECT [Date], LAG([Date]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS PrevDate
      FROM #Dates ) d
)
```

to produce the following result:

```
Date        rn  flag
===================
2015-01-01  1   0
2015-01-02  2   1
2015-01-03  3   1
2015-01-06  4   0
2015-01-07  5   1
2015-01-11  6   0
```

All you have to do now is to calculate a running total of `flag` *up to* the *first* occurrence of a *preceding* zero value:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   ... cte statements here ...
)
SELECT [Date], b.cnt + 1
FROM CTE AS c
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(rn, 1) AS rn 
   FROM CTE
   WHERE flag = 0 AND rn < c.rn
   ORDER BY rn DESC
) a 
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM CTE 
   WHERE c.flag <> 0 AND rn < c.rn AND rn >= a.rn
) b
```

`OUTER APPLY` calculates the `rn` value of the *first* zero-valued flag that comes before the current row. `CROSS APPLY` calculates the number of records preceding the current record *up to* the first occurrence of a preceding zero valued flag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this table:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Dates
FROM (VALUES
  (CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE)),
  (CAST('2015-01-02' AS DATE)),
  (CAST('2015-01-03' AS DATE)),
  (CAST('2015-01-06' AS DATE)),
  (CAST('2015-01-07' AS DATE)),
  (CAST('2015-01-11' AS DATE))) dates(d);
```

Here's a recursive solution with explanations:

```
WITH
  dates AS (
    SELECT
      d, 
      -- This checks if the current row is the start of a new group by using LAG()
      -- to see if the previous date is adjacent
      CASE datediff(day, d, LAG(d, 1) OVER(ORDER BY d)) 
        WHEN -1 THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 END new_group,
      -- This will be used for recursion
      row_number() OVER(ORDER BY d) rn
    FROM #Dates
  ),
  -- Here, the recursion happens
  groups AS (
    -- We initiate recursion with rows that start new groups, and calculate "GRP"
    -- numbers
    SELECT d, new_group, rn, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY d) grp
    FROM dates
    WHERE new_group = 1
    UNION ALL
    -- We then recurse by the previously calculated "RN" until we hit the next group
    SELECT dates.d, dates.new_group, dates.rn, groups.grp
    FROM dates JOIN groups ON dates.rn = groups.rn + 1
    WHERE dates.new_group != 1
  )
-- Finally, we enumerate rows within each group
SELECT d, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY d)
FROM groups
ORDER BY d
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23689)