# SQL subquery without loop through recordset

Tags: sql, loops, subquery

This is a simple query:

```
SELECT        fDATE, fRAIN
FROM            tRAIN
WHERE        (fRAIN >=5)
```

Retrieved query may be something like:

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k13V.png)

Now, i want to get the subset corresponding to the longer rainy season , in this case dates between october 9th and 13th. ¿There is a way to do this without looping through recordset?

I appreciate your help.  Regards

Comment: size of season is determined by count of consecutive days ?

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: Whats your Database?

Comment: check https://community.oracle.com/thread/1005633 for solution

Comment: Data base contains daily measurements since 2004 until current day. Several measurement stations are recorded. Queries are more complex than i´ve shown in the example, but the aim is to get longer rainy station. I can´t know from begining the date range that contains the longer rainy season. I know how to do this looping through records. I just want to know if there another way to do it without loop. Yes, count consecutive days with rain>= value and retrieve the longer serie is the aim. Thanks. – José Fernando Giraldo Jimenez 8 mins ago

Comment: sorry, "rainy station" is wrong. Read as rainy season. target is obtain length of longer serie (count consecutive days) and the beginning and end date. Optionally, sum of rain for serie.

Comment: Why is the 9th of october in your example in the longest raining period, when the 10th has an fRain-value of 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completed the task, guided by answer posted at [How to get count of consecutive dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249740/how-to-get-count-of-consecutive-dates)

```
WITH Q4 AS (
SELECT Q3.fDate, Q3.RW
FROM
(SELECT 
RW=ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY GRP  ORDER BY fDate) ,fDate
FROM
(
SELECT 
fDate, DATEDIFF(Day, '1900-01-01' , fDate)- ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY 
fDate ) AS GRP
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CONCAT(fYEAR , '/' , fMONTH , '/' ,fDAY),111) AS fDate, 
fRAIN 
FROM tRain
WHERE (fRain >= _value AND fStation = '_string' AND fYear = _value)
) Q1 
) Q2
) Q3
)
SELECT (DATEADD(DAY,-Q4.RW+1,Q4.fDate)) AS Start_Date, Q4.fDate AS 
Final_Date, Q4.RW as Season_Length
FROM Q4
WHERE Q4.RW= (SELECT TOP 1 MAX(Q4.RW) FROM Q4)
```

The output looks like:

[QUERY RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL9hL.png)

Regards