# SQL: how to group by dates in a row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

It might be already answered before, but apparently I am not googling it right.

Let's say I have a table:

```
RecordingDate
2018-07-01
2018-07-02
2018-07-06
2018-07-09
2018-07-10
2018-07-11
2018-07-12
2018-07-16
2018-07-17
2018-07-18
```

I want to group the data by the date of the first recording and count days in a row with recordings:

```
DateOfFirstRecording  RecordingsInARow
2018-07-01            2
2018-07-06            1
2018-07-09            4
2018-07-16            3
```

How do I do that ?

Comment: Create a date table and reference that: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: Do not expect readers to figure out how you want to compute additional columns. You need to specify these details.

Comment: @jpmc26, what additional columns you are talking about ?

Comment: The `RecordingsInARow` column.

Comment: @jpmc26 What is wrong with the explanation I have provided ?

Comment: It's unclear. You haven't specified how to handle edge cases (multiple recordings with the same date, for example). "In a row" is confusing terminology when "row" means something very specific in SQL. You probably mean "consecutive," but that isn't clear without staring at your question trying to figure out what you mean for 10 minutes and guessing based on your example output. You must provide crystal clear, straightforward explanations.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28249740/1394393 But it's hard to tell because both are presented in a manner that makes the details unclear .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subtract an increasing sequence, to get a constant date.  This is the idea:

```
select min(date), max(date), count(*)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by date - seqnum * interval '1 day'
order by min(date);
```

Date operations vary significantly depending on the database, but all databases support this functionality with some syntax.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, this looks like:

```
select 
    min(RecordingDate) as DateOfFirstRecording, 
    count(*) as RecordingsInARow
from (select Recordings.*, row_number() over (order by RecordingDate) as seqnum
      from Recordings
     ) t
group by dateadd(day, - seqnum, RecordingDate)
order by min(RecordingDate);
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That works for me!